# Периодически повторяющаяся ошибка "Incorrect key file for table"

Tags: mysql

На удалённом сервере периодически при работе приложения возникает ошибка наподобие:

> SQLException :  java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect key file for table
>   'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP#sql_a38_0.MYI'; try to repair it

или

> SQLException : java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect key file for table
>   'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP#sql_a38_25.MYI'; try to repair it

Вот пример одного из запросов, приведших к данной ошибке:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM  (select * from table1 union all select * from table2) a
WHERE  time > 1468443612608 AND time <= 1468530021572 
AND status=1
AND 1
GROUP BY a.cur ORDER BY null
```

Но возникает данная ошибка при выполнении различных запросов. При запуске и работе приложения на локальном сервера такой ошибки не наблюдается. В чём может быть причина данной ошибки? В различных источниках указывается, что данная ошибка может возникать при нехватке места для создания временных таблиц, но где именно его нужно увеличить и как?

Comment: > you can use the --tmpdir option to mysqld to specify a directory in a file system where you have enough space. А в принципе надо убрать мусор из temp, поставить хард побольше или изменить запрос, чтобы он не забирал слишком много данных. сделайте "EXPLAIN ваш_запрос"

Comment: @strangeqargo, при использовании EXPLAIN в поле Extra выводится "Using temporary", но изменить этот запрос нельзя.

Comment: что значит "нельзя"? надо изменить или запрос или индексы в бд, или то и другое. или добавить места на hdd. других вариантов у вас нет. если вы добавите место на hdd, но не оптимизируете запрос/индексы, запрос будет выполняться, но все медленней и медленней, до тех пор, пока его производительность не станет непримлемой. покажите пример.

Comment: @strangeqargo, добавила пример запроса

Comment: это очень плохой запрос.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    SELECT count(*) #первый запрос, который бесполезно 
                    #выбирает данные из своих подзапросов
    FROM  (
    #второй запрос, выбирает ВСЕ даннные без лимитов и ограничений
    select * from table1  
        union all 
    #третий запрос, выбирает ВСЕ даннные без лимитов и ограничений
    select * from table2
)  a
  #почему вы не ограничили time в подзапросах?        
      WHERE  time > 1468443612608 AND time <= 1468530021572 
      AND status=1 #почему вы не ограничили status=1  в подзапросах?
  # вот это кто-то где-то вычитал для какой-то оптимизации
  # не понимая, что делает
      AND 1 GROUP BY a.cur ORDER BY null
```

вы  делаете запрос, который выбирает **все** данные **за все время** из **обеих**  таблиц, а потом фильтруете вывод.

естественно, что база давится. кроме того, в подзапросах вы забираете `*` ВСЕ данные, хотя вам нужно только считать записи, а не выводить/обрабатывать данные

как минимум можно переписать так:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM  (
select cur  /* вместо "*" здесь должно быть нужное поле */   from table1 
WHERE status = 1 AND  (time > 1468443612608 AND time <= 1468530021572) 

union all 

select cur /* вместо "*" здесь должно быть нужное поле */ from table2
WHERE status = 1 AND  (time > 1468443612608 AND time <= 1468530021572) 
) a

GROUP BY a.cur;
```

я не знаю вашей задачи и архитектуры вашей базы, возможно - и *скорее всего*  - вам следовало использовать JOIN на `status=1` с WHERE, вместо UNION ALL

на локальном сервере у вас естественно таких ошибок не наблюдается, просто потому, что на локальном сервере у вас *мало* данных, а на продакшен сервере их *много*, это типичная ошибка начинающего веб-разработчика - предполагать, что если запрос выполняется быстро на тестовой базе, он будет отлично летать на боевой

не хотите (или не можете) изменить запрос: добро пожаловать в кошмарный мир плохих администраторов баз данных:

> you can use the --tmpdir option to mysqld to specify a directory in a
>   file system where you have enough space. Надо убрать мусор из temp,
>   поставить хард побольше или изменить запрос, чтобы он не забирал
>   слишком много данных.

можете еще памяти докинуть, еще полгода продержитесь без *страшных* тормозов.

P.S. 
я боюсь представить, что увижу если вы покажете результат выполнения `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Рекомендую вам отличную книгу: *MySQL. Оптимизация производительности*. Купите, одолжите, скачайте, получите в подарок, но прочитайте ее (необязательно всю, хотя бы релевантные вашему случаю главы), если хотите понимать, что вы делаете.

Comment: Спасибо за такой развёрнутый ответ! Действительно, я попробовала выполнить запрос с WHERE в подзапросах, разница во времени выполнения огромная)

Comment: книжку все равно добудьте, она хоть и про mysql но в целом про разные rdmbs вставляет мозги